# Understanding how all variables are objects

Tags: python

It is said that everything is object in python, I am not able to understand why following codes work in different ways:

```
foo=Foo()
print(foo)
```

Output: `<__main__.Foo object at 0x0000029ACB4DA978>`

```
a=10
print(a)
```

Output: `10`

Now if everything is an object, then why is `print(a)` is not printing what `print(foo)` did?

Comment: They are both objects, but have different [`__repr__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) implementations.

Comment: They both print *something*. There is no requirement to print the hex ID, that's just a default implementation for a class that has no better representation. Both objects have an id, see `id(a)` and `id(foo)`.

Comment: Thanks  @Martijn Pieters i guess i should have gone through the python doc, btw in extension to my question when any function is called in python does that mean another function inside the object of that function is called to execute the code.

Comment: `__repr__` is used if the REPL displays the object.  `__str__` is used when `print` displays the object.  However, the default implementation of `__str__` delegates to `__repr__`.

Answer (score 0):

`print` displays the string representation of an object by calling it's `__str__` method.  `Foo` appears to have inherited the default `__str__`, which returns a string showing the object's type and identity.  An `int` returns a string showing the decimal representation of its value.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `print( )` you are asking Python to display visual representation of the object so that we humans can see what it is. To print the object it must have a method `__str__` or `__repr__`.

For simple objects like strings `"your string"` or integers `123` the `__str__` method is used when you type `print(123)`.
That method is set to display the integer value then.

But for more complex objects and especially for objects created by the programmer (you) if you have not implemented your own `__str__` or `__repr__` method Python will just print function's (object's) name and address in memory where that object is located.

Once you get to deeper understanding of object oriented programming you will be able to create your own `__str__` and `__repr__` methods which will override then the basic method used by Python and display whatever information you want for that object.

Hope it helps a bit.

Tomasz Kluczkowski